# Unable to start MATLAB R2023a in Ubuntu Linux 23.04, it stops after "MATLAB is selecting SOFTWARE OPENGL rendering." message

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to solve this problem for hours, yet I don't have any solution. Looked through installation docs, but couldn't find why the problem occurs. I installed MATLAB R2023a without a problem via the ISO file which my school gave me. When I try to run the matlab, **"MATLAB is selecting SOFTWARE OPENGL rendering."** message comes and after a second, process stops without an error(?). The program wouldn't start either.

My gcc and g++ versions were 12, I downgraded them to 11 since its says the latest version it supports is 11 in Matlab docs. However it didn't work.

I also tried

```
./matlab -nosoftwareopengl
```

this time the message I mentioned earlier doesn't come up, but process again stops after a second.

I checked my system resources, my CPU usage increases for a second but memory usage stands still.

I installed two times into different locations to check if it's about permissions or whatnot, but it didn't help.

I tried other suggestions from web, but no help so far.

No solution yet.. I'd be happy if we can sort this out :(

My machine has AMD Ryzen 4600H as a CPU, and also integrated GPU known as AMD Radeon Graphics.

**UPDATE:**

I tried to use free-trial version from the website, it's R2023b and worked fine. These are the some logs after running it:

```
MATLAB is selecting SOFTWARE OPENGL rendering.
Fontconfig warning: "/usr/share/fontconfig/conf.avail/05-reset-dirs-sample.conf", line 6: unknown element "reset-dirs"
Gtk-Message: 21:36:13.537: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
MESA-LOADER: failed to open radeonsi: /usr/lib/dri/radeonsi_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
MESA-LOADER: failed to open zink: /usr/lib/dri/zink_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
MESA-LOADER: failed to open kms_swrast: /usr/lib/dri/kms_swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast: /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
```

Also when I run some basic tasks like imshow(), and rgb2gray(); it gives this warning:

```
Warning: MATLAB has disabled some advanced graphics rendering features by switching to software OpenGL. For more information, click here.
```

I'm adding these outputs for troubleshooting. If you need anything else, I can provide happily!

Comment: Maybe ask your school, since they gave you that ISO? If the official distribution you downloaded from their website works, then it must be your school's ISO that has a problem. It could be a licensing issue. Did you get any specific installation instructions from the school?

Comment: @CrisLuengo I wouldn't be liar if I say my school's IT people are useless in most cases. I emailed them, but pretty sure it won't help. They handout only an activation key, that's it.

Comment: Did you install the latest graphics drivers on linux? An incompatible or old driver can fail hardware accelerated graphics features. Another possible issue could be the remote desktop session. Did you try to run MATLAB in remote desktop session like VNC?

Comment: @CemPolat When I check for any updates & upgrades, I don't see anything for graphics driver. I think they are already up to date, how can I be sure?

Comment: check updates on mesa opengl driver "sudo apt search mesa". If there are any updates install with "sudo apt install mesa". Reboot the PC and retry.
You can run glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer" to get information about the installed OpenGL driver.

Comment: @CemPolat There isn't a package called specificly "mesa", I installed `mesa-utils` and ran `glxinfo`, and this was the output: `OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon Graphics (renoir, LLVM 15.0.7, DRM 3.49, 6.2.0-34-generic)`

Comment: Ubuntu may not be able to select the correct/up to date driver. try to manually install the Radeon driver from AMD site https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-23-20.

Comment: @CemPolat thanks for the info, apparently I'm unable to use amdgpu-install utility because of some dependency problems in my computer for some reason :( I will consider hopping into some other distribution when my free trial ends. (It's weird that the free trial version works just fine though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by providing a `license.dat` file from my school. This file is requested in the install, but I was able to skip it because it didn't force me to. Also it didn't give any error. Anyway, it's solved.